# How can I remove any specific installed node package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, single-page-application, package.json

In the process of developing a single page application I installed some npm package like

```
npm install react-currency-format --save
```

also

```
npm install react-slick --save
```

But I want to remove these items. Without any effect on rest of the code.

How can I do it?

Comment: `npm uninstall react-currency-format`

Comment: or `npm un react-currency-format` for short